# What makes every strong monad on a certain category be a monoidal functor?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, monoidal-categories, monads

A concept named [Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) is used a lot in functional programming. And in spite their definition is not completely same with the definition of monad in category theory, as I know, Monad on a programming language is equivalent to certain category theoretical monad. The category has [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) as objects and [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) between them as morphisms. Since data types can be seen as a set of values, it's simply a subcategory of Set.

I found that in functional programming, a Monad is always an [Applicative Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor), which is said to be 'programming equivalent of a lax monoidal functor with tensorial strength in category theory.'

Exactly how is this possible? Specifically, What makes monad on Set always be a monoidal functor?

I tried to prove this from that every monad in Set are strong monad, but failed. The only thing I could find was that strong monads are monoidal if they are [commutative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+monad). The problem is that even in the category of sets, monads are not commmutative in general. There are many monad which are not commutative in Set, including free monoid monad.

Just proving that every monad in Set are monoidal functor perhaps not be that hard. I rather want to know more fundamental, or generalizable reason behind that. (If exist.) What makes every strong monad in certain category be always monoidal functor, even when they are not commutative?

Comment: The monoidal structure on $\textbf{Set}$ is the cartesian product (usually). It is not true that every endofunctor on $\textbf{Set}$ is lax monoidal. (However, every endofunctor on $\textbf{Set}$ is oplax monoidal.) Every monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is strong, basically because for any endofunctor $T$ you always have a natural map $X \times T Y \to T (X \times Y)$: just think of $X \times Y$ as $\coprod_{x \in X} Y$ and use the universal property of coproducts.

Comment: I think you didn't answered the question yet. What I want to know is whether every monad on Set are monoidal functors or not. (If not, there must be an example of monad in programming which is not an applicative functor, for the type category on which the monad is can be an arbitrary subcategory of Set because languages can support any types as they want in principle.)

Comment: Not every monad is lax monoidal. In my terminology anyway. Some people use the opposite convention and say lax for what I say is oplax.

Comment: Is there any monad in Set which is not a lax monoidal functor for the canonical tensorial strength? The free monoid monad was lax monoidal as I checked, even though it's not commutative.

Comment: The reason commutativity isn't necessary is that the $T$ is always being pulled out in the same left-to-right (or right-to-left) nesting, just associated differently. However, to generalize from $\mathbf{Set}$ you'll likely need to consider a symmetric, or at least braided, monoidal category. So, that should give you that $T$ is a monoidal functor on such a $C$, but not a _symmetric_ monoidal functor (which would require commutativity of $T$). If that's not sufficient information I can try to work out the details as an answer, but that's the general shape of how it would work.

Comment: Another option would be to consider both a left and right strength for $T$ (which is what symmetry is giving). But they need to be compatible, so that $TA \otimes (TB \otimes TC)$ ends up the same as $(TA \otimes TB) \otimes TC$, even though that switches which strength is used for $TB$. But, it might be simpler to prove that that gives a lax monoidal structure for $T$, and then prove that a strong monad on a symmetric monoidal category gives a compatible pair of strengths.

Comment: @Antel The free monoid monad is not lax monoidal. As you say, a lax monoidal strong monad would be commutative. Every monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is strong. Not every monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is commutative: for example, the free monoid monad is not commutative. I don't know what natural transformation $T X \times T Y \to T (X \times Y)$ you have in mind, but you should probably recheck your work.

Comment: I have the most canonical $ TX \times TY \rightarrow T(X \times Y) $ in mind. Apply strength, then apply T(costrength), then multiply. It would be like $ TX \times TY \rightarrow T(TX \times Y) \rightarrow TT(X \times Y) \rightarrow T(X \times Y) $.

Comment: This $ TX \times TY \rightarrow T(X \times Y)  $ is indeed not commutative, but $ T $ makes a lax monoidal functor with this. Assume three free monoid $  \{ x_1, \cdots x_n \} $,  $  \{ y_1, \cdots y_m \} $ and $  \{ z_1, \cdots z_l \} $ as arbitrary elements of $ TX $, $ TY $ and $ TZ $. One can show that $ (TX \times TY) \times TZ \rightarrow T(X \times Y) \times TZ \rightarrow T((X \times Y) \times Z) \rightarrow T(X \times (Y \times Z)) $ is equal to $ (TX \times TY) \times TZ \rightarrow TX \times (TY \times TZ ) \rightarrow TX \times T(Y \times Z) \rightarrow T(X \times (Y \times Z)) $

Comment: @Zhen Lin $ T $ is not a monoidal monad, of course. To be a monoidal monad, it should be commutative monad first. What I'm saying is $ T $ is a monad based on a monoidal functor. I guess things don't have to be a commutative monad just to be a monad with a monoidal functor.

Comment: @Dan Doel Thank you for the explanation. I think I can just take it as an answer if it's correct. Sadly, the only way to prove things in category theory I know is just connecting commuting diagrams here and there. The commutation condition for the coherence maps are already too big, especially when the maps are the composition of three transformations themselves. If braidings also need in this picture... I doubt if I can do it by myself.

Comment: @Dan Doel Anyway, I just wanted to know when the condition can be generalized. Your answer is perfect in this regard. It would be greater if I can see the details but as you can see, I'm new here and I have no point to give you. I guess it wouldn't be worth for you to spend time on this.

Comment: @Antel I'm not convinced. For one thing, it cannot be ”the most canonical" because you could also apply the costrength first and then $T(\text{strength})$. These will give you different natural transformations: one way sends $(x_1 \cdots x_n, y_1 \cdots y_m)$ to $x_1 y_1 \cdots y_m x_2 y_1 \cdots y_m \cdots x_n y_1 \cdots y_m$, the other way gives $x_1 \cdots x_n y_1 x_1 \cdots x_n y_2 \cdots x_1 \cdots x_n y_m$. Neither one is "associative".

Comment: There exist two ways to define coherence maps and both are associative. For example,$  \{x_1,x_2\} \{y_1, y_2 \} \{z_1, z_2\} \rightarrow \{ x_1 y_1, x_1 y_2, x_2 y_1, x_2 y_2 \}  \{z_1, z_2 \} \rightarrow \{  x_1 y_1 z_1, x_1 y_1 z_2, x_1 y_2z_1, x_1 y_2z_2, x_2 y_1z_1, x_2 y_1z_2, x_2 y_2z_1, x_2 y_2z_2 \} $ gives same result with $  \{x_1,x_2\} \{y_1, y_2 \} \{z_1, z_2\} \rightarrow \{x_1,x_2\} \{ y_1 z_1, y_1 z_2, y_2 z_1, y_2 z_2 \}  \rightarrow \{  x_1 y_1 z_1, x_1 y_1 z_2, x_1 y_2z_1, x_1 y_2z_2, x_2 y_1z_1, x_2 y_1z_2, x_2 y_2z_1, x_2 y_2z_2 \} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

Suppose $T$ has *two* tensorial strengths:

$$σ : A \otimes TB → T (A \otimes B) \\ τ : TA \otimes B → T (A \otimes B)$$

with the compatibility condition:

$$
\begin{CD}
A \otimes(TB \otimes C) @>{α}>> (A \otimes TB) \otimes C \\
@V{A \otimes τ}VV @VV{σ \otimes C}V \\
A \otimes T (B \otimes C) @. T(A \otimes B) \otimes C \\
@V{σ}VV @VV{τ}V \\
T(A \otimes (B \otimes C)) @>>{Tα}> T((A \otimes B) \otimes C)
\end{CD}
$$

This is apparently known as a bistrength. Then we can try to define a monoidal multiplication as:

$$m : T A \otimes T B → T(A \otimes B) \\
m = μ \circ Tσ \circ τ$$

I assume only the associativity is in question. That is the diagram:

$$
\begin{CD}
TA \otimes (TB \otimes TC) @>{α}>> (TA \otimes TB) \otimes TC \\
@V{TA \otimes m}VV @VV{m \otimes TC}V \\
TA \otimes T(B \otimes C) @. T(A \otimes B) \otimes TC \\
@V{m}VV @VV{m}V \\
T (A \otimes (B \otimes C)) @>>{Tα}> T((A \otimes B) \otimes C)
\end{CD}
$$

Here's an equational proof:

$$
\begin{align}
&\ μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ ∘ ((μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ)⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ ∘ (μ⊗TC) ∘ ((Tσ ∘ τ)⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ Tσ ∘ μ ∘ Tτ ∘ τ ∘ ((Tσ ∘ τ)⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ Tτ ∘ τ ∘ ((Tσ ∘ τ)⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ Tτ ∘ τ ∘ (Tσ⊗TC) ∘ (τ⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ Tτ ∘ T(σ⊗TC) ∘ τ ∘ (τ⊗TC) ∘ α
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ Tτ ∘ T(σ⊗TC) ∘ Tα ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ T(τ ∘ (σ⊗TC) ∘ α) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ T(Tα ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗τ)) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTσ ∘ TTα ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TT(σ ∘ α) ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TT(Tα ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗σ)) ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ TT(A⊗σ) ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ T(T(A⊗σ) ∘ σ) ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ T(σ ∘ (A⊗Tσ)) ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗Tσ) ∘ T(A⊗τ) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ TTσ ∘ T(σ ∘ (A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ μ ∘ TTTα ∘ T(Tσ ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ Tμ ∘ TTTα ∘ T(Tσ ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ TTα ∘ Tμ ∘ T(Tσ ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ TTα ∘ T(μ ∘ Tσ ∘ σ ∘ (A⊗(Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ TTα ∘ T(σ ∘ (A⊗(μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ))) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ μ ∘ TTα ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗(μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ)) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ Tα ∘ μ ∘ Tσ ∘ T(A⊗(μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ)) ∘ τ
\\ = &\ Tα ∘ μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ ∘ (TA⊗(μ ∘ Tσ ∘ τ))
\end{align}
$$

There's also the opposite order multiplication which does $τ$ after $σ$, and should have a similar proof.

The informal answer is: this sort of tensorial bi-strength lets us go from $T A \otimes TB$ to $T^2(A \otimes B)$. Then the monad multiplication lets us flatten down to $T(A \otimes B)$. This is associative as long as the two strengths are 'the same' operation just for opposite sides of the tensor.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the detailed answer. By the way, I found that you didn't use any braiding here. Isn't this work for all bistrong monads? Why the condition that 'the two strengths are the same operation' needs?

Comment: Yes, this works for any bistrong monad on a monoidal category. The compatibility condition is needed because reassociating from $TA \otimes (TB \otimes TC)$ to $(TA \otimes TB) \otimes TC$ changes how the $TB$ part is lifted, and the ways need to be equal for associativity to hold. That is the fact that is used in lines 8->9 in the above proof. If there is a braiding, then it should be possible to get a second strength given just a strong monad. I'm unsure if showing that this is bistrong requires symmetric monoidal, or just braided monoidal.